# Can I handle class as objects in C++

Tags: c++, class

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
I have a list of Classes (Class1 to Classn) which inherit from a main Class
I would like to be able to instanciate an object of any of the n classes without having to do a large switch case (or equivalent). something along the lines of:

```
static ClassPointerType const * const ArrayOfClassTypes[]={ Class1, Class2, .. Classn }; 

static Class *GetObjectOfClass(int i)
{
  return new ArrayOfClassTypes[i](some parameters for the constructor);
}
```

You can do that in other OO langues like Delphi where you have a TClass type and can get the class of an object... but I was not able to locate the equivalent functionality in C++.

Comment: Do the classes all share the same constructor signature?

Comment: Fearing asking this, I'll do so with blatant disregard none-the-less. Are you looking for something similar to the class-loader in Java ? (I see you already mentioned Delphi, but alas my familiarity stopped once I found the Joy of C++).

Comment: object = instance of a class. Therefore your title makes no sense. As for the real question - it is not possible

Comment: @BЈовић: The title makes sense in other OO languages, where the equivalent of `std::type_info` is more powerful.

Comment: The title makes sense in lots of languages where all object derive from CObject and where CObject always has a member pointer which is an instance of CClass (which itself derives from CObject of course).
So, if you get a hold of the instance of CClass which defines a specific class, you can call methods on it, such as a 'new' or create which will in turn allow you to allocate an object which is an instance of the class defined by your CClass instance! lovely!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<base> make()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<base>(new T);
}

class factory
{
    static constexpr std::unique_ptr<Base> (*fns[])(){make<derived_a>, make<derived_b>};

    std::unique_ptr<base> get_object_of_class(int const i)
    {
        if (i < 0 || sizeof fns / sizeof *fns <= i) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return fns[i]();
    }
};
```

Comment: This is nice in general, but I don't really like the tight coupling between the factory and all the classes it can create. I'd prefer to have a static constructor in the derived class and a static member that registered the class with the factory. Plus, I'd start off using strings as identifiers rather than integers.

Comment: @Skizz: The basic idea is the same: Use an array of creation functions. How it fits the design can be left to OP.

Comment: It works! Thanks.
It is not as clean as I would have liked (as what it really does it creates 1 function for every class type that I need), but at least I do not have to manually create the said functions...

Comment: Slick solution. I didn't go the unique_ptr direction and kinda wish I did. I needed variadic expansion at the point of usage rather than the point of the class, [but that was pretty trivial](http://ideone.com/AWGtBb). I don't think variadic args to the functions are doable though, at least not trivially. gotta gel on that for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

You can add virtual method Clone to your base class and have it pure virtual (= NULL). Have there all required parameters.

Then you can override it in every subclass and create concrete classes there.

And in your factory do:

```
static ClassPointerType *GetObjectOfClass(int i)
{
  return new ArrayOfClassTypes[i]->Clone(some params for the constructor);
}
```

And your array should contain concrete classes which you will clone:

```
static ClassPointerType* const ArrayOfClassTypes[]={ new ClassPointerType1(),new ClassPointerType2(), .. new ClassPointerTypeN() };
```

Complete example as requested:

```
// base class
class ClassPointerType
{
…
public:
    virtual ClassPointerType* Clone(your params) = NULL;
};

// concrete classes
class ClassPointerType1 : public ClassPointerType
{
…
    public:
        // note: it clones own concrete instance
        virtual ClassPointerType* Clone(your params) {return new ClassPointerType1(your params)};
}

class ClassPointerType2 : public ClassPointerType
{
…
    public:
        virtual ClassPointerType* Clone(your params) {return new ClassPointerType2(your params)};
}
…


class ClassPointerTypeN : public ClassPointerType
{
…
    public:
        virtual ClassPointerType* Clone(your params) {return new ClassPointerTypeN(your params)};
}
```

Comment: @BЈовић All this appears to do is localize your same question to a different function, but I'm rather curious of the followup myself.

Comment: In `ClassPointerType1`, you're allowed to write `virtual ClassPointerType1* Clone(your params) {return new ClassPointerType1(your params)}; }`. It's called covariance.

Comment: That is what I had at the begining of my design, I was just getting fed up of having to continusly create these clone (actually, create in my case) funtions in each sub class..

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something alike recently. In my approach I stored a list of static create-functions instead and feeded a factory class with that

I implemented a templated base class wich

a) is able to register the derived into a factory class

b) implicitly forces the derived class to provide static functions.

However, you have to announce each derived class once. You can use it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DerivedA::announce();

    //and later
    IInterface * prt = SingeltonFactory::create(DerivedA::_type);

    delete prt;

    return 0;
}
```

The Derived class DerivedA is defined as:

```
class DerivedA :
      public IInterface,
      public StaticBase<DerivedA>
{
public:
    using StaticBase::announce;
    static IInterface * create(){ return new DerivedA; }
    static const std::string _type;

};
const std::string DerivedA::_type=std::string("DerivedA");
```

And the static Base class forcing the _type attribute and the create function to exist are defined as follows:

```
template<class TDerived>
class StaticBase
{
protected:
    static void announce()
    {
        // register into factory:
        SingeltonFactory::registerFun(TDerived::_type,TDerived::_create());
        // The call of _type and _create implicitly forces the derived class to implement these, if it is deriving from this Base class
    }
};
```

The factory class does contain a map of

```
std::map<std::string,tFunPtr>
```

where typedef tFunPtr is:

```
typedef IInterface * (*tFunPtr)(void);
```

This map you can use as an "array of classes" in order to handle it like an object. Thus, you represent the classes by a function pointer of the *static* create function

Does this answer your requirements? Shall I provide the factory class?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a C++11 compiler here is a solution equivalent to the one provided earlier but less tricky and clever:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class Der1: public Base {
private:
    void doSomething() override {
    std::cout << "Der1 did something" << std::endl;
}
};

class Der2: public Base {
private:
    void doSomething() override {
    std::cout << "Der2 did something" << std::endl;
}

};

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Base> make() {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T);
}

int main() {

    std::array<std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>(void)>, 2> arr{make<Der1>,
                                                                  make<Der2>};

    auto obj = arr[0]();
    obj->doSomething();
    obj = arr[1]();
    obj->doSomething();
}
```

You can use std::bind too to pass arguments to make if you have to use a non-default contructor

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

No, in C++ classes are not first-order entities.

(I just noticed everybody is providing a solution to your problem but not precisely answering your question.)